# Showing monthly instead of specific data. Small tweak needed

Tags: sql

I want to show the Total Invoices per Month by Job Type, but it seems that it is shwoing the monthly total. I just want to show the total per job type.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
select `vinvoices`.`yymm` AS `yymm`,
`vinvoices`.`location` AS `job_location`,
`vinvoices`.`job_no` AS `job_no`,
format(sum(`vinvoices`.`amount`),0) AS `amount`,
`tjobtypes`.`type_name` AS `type` from ((`vinvoices` join `tjobs` on((`tjobs`.`job_no` = `vinvoices`.`job_no`))) join `tjobtypes` on((`tjobtypes`.`type_no` = `tjobs`.`type_no`))) 
group by `vinvoices`.`yymm`,`vinvoices`.`location`
```

Here are the fields for vinvoices:

- date
- job_no - this connects to jobtypes field via the tjobs table
- job_name
- client_name
- amount
- ppaid
- inv_no
- prob
- notes
- contact
- location
- yymm

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()`, like this:

```
select `vinvoices`.`yymm` AS `yymm`,
`vinvoices`.`location` AS `job_location`,
`vinvoices`.`job_no` AS `job_no`,
format(COUNT(`vinvoices`.`amount`),0) AS `amount`,
`tjobtypes`.`type_name` AS `type` from ((`vinvoices` join `tjobs` on((`tjobs`.`job_no` = `vinvoices`.`job_no`))) join `tjobtypes` on((`tjobtypes`.`type_no` = `tjobs`.`type_no`))) 
group by `vinvoices`.`yymm`,`vinvoices`.`location`
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I need to get the sum of the amount field

Comment: @kinsesyete, I am not sure with your question, will you please tell me more about!!!

Comment: Sure, I just want to list the invoices by job type number from (tjobs table) by month. For now, it's showing the invoices monthly. 
Fields for invoices is updated on the post.

Comment: I have simple example in which query results employee salary total based on joining months, like (sum of all employee salary who joined in January, all in February and so on):

`select sum(salary),to_char(hire_date,'Mon') from employees group by to_char(hire_date,'Mon');`

hope this will give you hint solving your problem...

Comment: I dont get it. Please explain